# pulling dates out of a string

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching

My problem is as follows:

I have an array of strings that contain dates and other data. My date will have one of several formats:

1. dd/mm/yyyy
2. dd/mm/yy
3. mm/yy
4. d/m/yy
5. yyyy
6. yy

Is there a way to search a string for numbers that fit that pattern in the string?

In addition, it would be nice if I could check if the dd is between 1 and 31 inclusive etc, but it would not be so bad if I had to do that afterwards.

Comment: There is this cool thing called regex ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each of these corresponds to a regex.

Here are regexes for each:

- dd/mm/yyyy ==> `\b(?:[012][1-9]|3[01])/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4}\b`
- dd/mm/yy ==> `\b(?:[012][1-9]|3[01])/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/\d{2}\b`
- mm/yy ==> `\b(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/\d\d\b`
- d/m/yy ==> `\b[1-9]/[1-9]/\d\d\b`
- yyyy ==> `\b\d{4}\b`
- yy ==> `\b\d\d\b`

Of course, you can combine these together in different ways.  You can even make one super regex.

The last one is rather interesting, though.  I can imagine a case where you might have a plain old number in your text, like `42` that might not actually correspond to a year. Still I guess you can postprocess that.

Happy regexing.

**ADDENDUM**

To answer some questions in the comments:

1. Yes it works at the beginning and the end of the string, because `\b` is a *word boundary*, which includes all transitions from word characters (letters, digits, and underscores) to non-word characters and vice-versa, including the beginning and ending of the string.
2. To see tests, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wRufK/.  Yes I know this is in JavaScript and not C#, but jsfiddle is a very convenient way to show code in action.  There are differences though -- in C# we use `Regex.match` and the JavaScript regex has extra backslashes to escape the inner forward slashes.
3. `indexOf` *might* be overkill depending on the application.  If you want to find all matches, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx for info on repeated matching.  You can also modify the regexes for capturing.
4. Since your dates can be in any of the forms above, and probably others, a single regex might be preferable.  A very flexible date finder is here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html.  You might want to consider it instead of fixing an exact set.

Comment: How do I implement this? (store it in a string)

Comment: Can I call something like IndexOf to find out where in the string it is?

Comment: Check out Regex.Match().  The Match object returned will have the starting position of the matched string.

Comment: Should I do multiple regexes, or just one with a '|' seperating each one item, and if I only do one, how do I know how long the date is?

Comment: The Match object also has the length of the match as well as the value matched.

Comment: One last thing. Does \b work if its the first or last thing in the string?

Comment: @soandos Answers to your questions added to my answer.  Feel free to ask more.

Comment: Apologies for asking so many questions but: if there is more than one match, where will the other matches be?

Comment: And is there a way for it to treat '-' and '/' characters the same way, or should I just replace all of one with the other in the string, and work from there?

Comment: All matches can be found by calling `Regex.Matches` which returns a `MatchCollection` object.  There is a complete example here: http://geekswithblogs.net/rahul/archive/2005/08/16/50330.aspx.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Regarding `/` and `-`, the regex `[/\-]` means _either a slash or a dash_.  The dash is escaped here because inside of square brackets it is usually a range indicator.

Comment: Last one: it appears that if I feed it @"05\07\2434 this is a test" as the string, the regex returns just 05, as I guess that was the first match it was testing for (though it seems to me that it was the last one one the list). How can I fix it so that it goes for the longest matches first?

Comment: Did you put all choices in a single regex separated with `|`?  If so, they are checked in order from left to right.  Putting the longest regex first in there should do the trick.  Note your example in your comment uses backslashes; maybe that was the issue?

Comment: Thank you for you help. that was the issue.